# Is there any way to fix python mayavi error as described below?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mayavi

I am trying to execute a python code which has Mayavi. After compilation, I should have got the figure. But I have got an empty screen with the following warnings.

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, with Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (32-bit). Any help will highly be useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested by myself.. But take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635851/error-in-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04) answer

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 mayavi2
```